# Drilling into reports

Tags: gooddata

I have a headline stat drilling into a separate report showing table data for that stat.

- Headline Stat: # of Widgets
- Filterable by in Dashboard:
- Widget Category
- Date (Timeline)
- App Store Status
  Drills into a report showing: Widget Name, Widget Developer, Widget Description, Date (Submitted)

The drill into report is filtered correctly by widget category but NOT by the timeline filter. It’s showing Widget info across all submission dates. The headline stat for my applied dashboard filters is showing 7 Widgets, however the drill in report is showing a much larger group. However, I want the dashboard filters including the timeline dimension to apply to the Drill Across report. I cannot change the drill-in report to display based on Date (Timeline) - the report says it’s not available for the data I selected.

Answer (score 0):

Drilling into the reports can be dependant on a few different things, and if you are unable to select the date filter it is most likely related to the fact that the date dimension is not connected to the other objects used in the report within the Logical Data Model. You will need to make sure the dataset is connected accordingly within the LDM.

If the date dimension is connected and used correctly within the metrics and you are still not seeing your desired results, then I would suggest the following:

- Check [project validation](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/enterprise/en/workspace-and-user-administration/administrating-workspaces-and-workspace-objects/validate-a-workspace)
- Make sure all filters are applied correctly

If you are still facing issues, there are some MAQL tricks you can use when working with filters within your metric. For example, using [Parent Keywords](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/enterprise/en/dashboards-and-insights/maql-analytical-query-language/maql-expression-reference/filter-expressions/overriding-parent-filters/parent-filters).